# Creating a client for java web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I have created a simple java web service class like follows

```
public class Customer {
private String customerName;

public String getCustomerName() {
return customerName;
}

public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
this.customerName = customerName;
}
```

I did this using Eclipse Indigo enterprise edition & I used Axis2 as soap engine. Every thing fine.I created web service successfully & deployed it on Tomcat 7 server(wsdl also ok).
Now I want create a client program which can update the name variable. I created web service client using Eclipse & it generates CustomerCallbackHandler & CustomerStub java classes automatically. But I don't know how to develop a client using that classes to update variable. Please help me....

I implemented a client like this...

```
 import java.rmi.RemoteException;
 import com.spikes.ws.CustomerWSStub.SetName;
 import com.spikes.ws.CustomerWSStub.GetNameResponse;;
   public class TestClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException{
    CustomerWSStub.SetName obj = new CustomerWSStub.SetName();
    obj.setName("Kenth");

    CustomerWSStub.GetNameResponse res = new CustomerWSStub.GetNameResponse();
    System.out.println(res.get_return());
}
```

}

But when I'm running the code It gives "null" as result. What is wrong?? & how can I correct that ??? please help me.....

Comment: Can you call your service using a test tool such as soapUI? Can you see your WSDL (definition of your service)? You should google JAX-WS and how to create a client starting from WSDL. If you just want to test your service then soapUI is good enough on it's own, you wouldn't need a Java client at all.

Comment: I need to create java client. Wsdl & all the other things are ok. I want only to know how develop java client class by using auto generated callback handlers & stubs in Eclipse...

Comment: Does it work with a soapui client? That will verify that your server end is working ok

Comment: I don't know how Indigo works but what is it that stores your customer instance?  Does your `Customer` class get instantiated and then lives for the life of the application?  Can you put a log message or println in the server to see if it is being set?  Could it be another instance of `Customer` that you are hitting with the get call?

Comment: I'm new to programming & I don't know how to implement soapUI client. I just tried to implement java client.
println outputs null only. that is the problem......

Answer (score 0):

Please list your webservice method.  You have listed, I'm assuming the class you pass up.

```
CustomerWSStub.SetName obj = new CustomerWSStub.SetName();    
obj.setName("Kenth");
```

You need to call the web method on the class

```
CustomerWSStub.SetName obj = new CustomerWSStub.SetName();    
obj.setName("Kenth");  

CustomerWSStub stub = new CustomerWSStub();
CustomerWSStub.GetNameResponse res = stub.GetName(obj);
```

Please post your actual web service method and that will be helpful.